# Altium - Must be an easier way to adjust bus spacing after the fact?

Tags: altium, layout

I often use multi-routing to make traces nicely / evenly spaced. Generally, I try to make the bus spacing fairly large to reduce crosstalk, however, I often have to change this to create more space later and have not found an easy way to do so. Usually, I more or less re-route the whole thing. It would be nice if this was an option in the interactive sliding properties or something. Does anyone have any tips or tricks? Google didn't turn up much.

Comment: Do you use push/shove mode while routing? Granted it usually makes an ugly mess of things as it panics to find a place to put things, or snaps your pretty routes into the shortest, least pleasing ones, but...

Comment: Hey, thanks, I tried playing around with the push/shove mode more and it works pretty well for this. I just needed to set up some temporary clearance rules before doing it as the bus spacing I want is much larger than the minimum spacing on the board, but is a big improvement from what I was doing previously.

Comment: I suppose to do it properly, you'd need to specify what and where you're making a "bus", and set up all the rules on that. Which is fine if you have a big bus spanning a board, but if you're busing signals together more haphazardly, that's a lot harder. Also where they aren't bused, you might want the minimum clearance to apply, or need exceptions for fanout for example. There are some ways to do that, but it's not going to be easy to specify everything from first principles. On the upside, maybe the autorouter would give actually good results, pleasing even.

Comment: There are some features that can help with those (net classes, From-Tos, etc.), or tricks/hacks (net bridges, say), but yeah.